.Net Multiple Identical querystring parameters
I'm new to .Net, but not cgi programming and I'm having trouble finding concrete examples of the magic that .net does to map querystring parameters.
I have a controller endpoint that looks like this:
[HttpGet("search/{search}"]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<Results>>> SearchStuff(string search, [FromQuery]List<string> description)

This endpoint is supposed to accept requests that look like, .../search/searchme?description=asd&description=qwe&description=zxc
It took me forever to find the notation for the [FromQuery] which ensures it doesn't try and convert the List argument into a body subsmission.
Can anyone point me to the documentation for all supported cgi notations and what they do?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0#sources
it's specifically an aspnet feature, not a .net one.
This section should help.
In particular
[FromQuery] - Gets values from the query string.
[FromRoute] - Gets values from route data.
[FromForm] - Gets values from posted form fields.
[FromBody] - Gets values from the request body.
[FromHeader] - Gets values from HTTP headers.

The section on Collections in Model Binding in ASP.NET Core covers this.

Form or query string data can be in one of the following formats:

selectedCourses=1050&selectedCourses=2000
selectedCourses[0]=1050&selectedCourses[1]=2000
[0]=1050&[1]=2000
selectedCourses[a]=1050&selectedCourses[b]=2000&selectedCourses.index=a&selectedCourses.index=b
[a]=1050&[b]=2000&index=a&index=b


